# Nlog - Web.config rules - log file only for Global.asax file?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nlog

I am trying to add an extra log file to my existing NLog implementation.
I already have an Nlog file logger, but I want to add another for certain logs.

I am having trouble keeping these logs separate, as the existing calls use `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` and it seems to just append onto the log I want to keep separate.

The new log file should only be populated by logs in the Global.asax file, but adding that ruleset to the Web.config does not work. Is there a special way to define a rule for the Global.asax file?

**Global.asax file**

```
namespace TestOne.Browser
{
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using System.Web.Routing;
using DataAnnotationsExtensions.ClientValidation;

using WebMatrix.WebData;

public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_EndRequest()
    {
        ...

        var logger = LogManager.GetLogger("diagnosticsfile");
        logger.Info("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}", user, pageName, totalClientTimings, duration);

        ...
    }
}
}
```

**Web.config file**

```
<nlog>
    <variable name="root" value="C:/TestOne/Logs/Browser" />
    <targets>
      <target name="file" type="File" header="Starting logging..." footer="Stopping logging..." layout="${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd HH\:mm\:ss.fff} ${uppercase:${level}} ${callsite} ${aspnet-user-identity}${newline}${message} ${exception:format=ToString:maxInnerExceptionLevel=5}" fileName="${root}/Browser.log" archiveFileName="${root}/Archive/Browser.{##}.log" createDirs="true" archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Rolling" maxArchiveFiles="31" concurrentWrites="false" keepFileOpen="false" />
      <target name="diagnosticsfile" type="File" header="Time, LogType, User, PageName, TotalClientTimings, Duration (ms)" layout="${longdate},${level:uppercase=true},${message}" fileName="${root}/DiagnosticsLog.log" archiveFileName="${root}/Archive/Diagnostics.{##}.log" createDirs="true" archiveEvery="Day" archiveNumbering="Rolling" maxArchiveFiles="31" concurrentWrites="false" keepFileOpen="false" />
    </targets>
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
      <logger name="TestOne.Browser.MvcApplication" minlevel="Info" writeTo="diagnosticsfile" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
```

With this current configuration, nothing gets written to my diagnostics file (the new log file).
If I replace the `TestOne.Browser.MvcApplication` with `*` in the Nlog rules, the file gets written to, but then the existing logs in other classes that use `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger()` sometimes append to the diagnostics log (which they should not do). Is there a way to configure this so that doesn't happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logging rules decides where logger-output should be written. Your logging-rules says that ONLY loggers with name `TestOne.Browser.MvcApplication` should write to the `diagnosticsfile`-target:

```xml
    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
      <logger name="TestOne.Browser.MvcApplication" minlevel="Info" writeTo="diagnosticsfile" />
    </rules>
```

But in your code you are using `LogManager.GetLogger("diagnosticsfile")`:

To specify that logger-name `diagnosticsfile` should write to the diagnosticsfile-target, you can do like this:

```xml
    <rules>
      <logger name="diagnosticsfile" minlevel="Info" writeTo="diagnosticsfile" final="true" />
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Trace" writeTo="file" />
    </rules>
```

Notice the `final="true"` to ensure logger-output will not flow to the catch-all-rule that writes to `file`-target.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial

See also: https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules

Comment: Thank you, this worked!